# Can't register runner after installing Gitlab CI 4.0

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

For some reason I keep getting the "Failed to register this runner. Perhaps your SSH key is invalid or you are having network problems" error as I try to register a runner on our staging server.

I have Gitlab 6.3 and Gitlab CI 4.0 coordinator installed on the same server and am trying to install the runner on a separate staging server. Gitlab CI coordinator side seems to be working. I can login to the CI site and it sees my Gitlab repos and I can add the project to the CI on the Gitlab CI site.

The one issue I did run into prior is that I installed Gitlab CI 4.0 while I had Gitlab 6.1 running before I realized Gitlab 6.3 was a prereq for Gitlab CI 4.0. I then upgraded Gitlab to 6.3.

Should I maybe try and re-install Gitlab 4.0 from scratch again? Any suggestions on where I should try and look?

Answer (score 1):

The advice given on the similar [gitlab-ci issue 339](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/339#issuecomment-31008021) seems sound (and the first thing to check), by [Nate Bird (`natebird`)](https://github.com/natebird):

> Double check the token you are providing.
>   For some strange reason my copy/paste cut off the first character. I had this same issue last night.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this could be because the instructions to [setup nginx on the runner page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/gitlab-ci/README.md) aren't complete. The correct instructions are given [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md). In particular, nginx needs to know what to do when the runner comes in via https.

Answer (score 0):

I hit [incompatibility issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2275).

The sugested solution to downgrade ci-runner with `sudo apt install gitlab-ci-multi-runner=1.11.1` helped me. It would be fine to verify, if you are trying to use compatible versions.